# Add search feature and a toggle status dropdown to automations list built using SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have a built a Status dashboard for SFMC using SSJS. But now i want to add a search feature and a toggle status dropdown to the automations list.

For the search feature
I need the search feature to search by Name and it should appear above the table, and have the results should sit above the table with the same column titles as the table.

For the toggle feature to sit either next the search bar or in the status title area i wanted their to be a drop down menu that once a variable status object was select only those appeared in the table with the same column titles as the table.

"-1":"Error",
"0":"BuildingError",
"1":"Building",
"2":"Ready",
"3":"Running",
"4":"Paused",
"5":"Stopped",
"6":"Scheduled",
"7":"Awaiting Trigger",
"8":"InactiveTrigger"

I am fairly new to SSJS so excuse me if this seems pretty basic but i cant find any help online or i don't know what to look for exactly.

Here is my code so far:

```
<script runat="server">

  Platform.Load("Core","1");

  var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

  var cols = ["Name","Status","LastRunTime","ProgramID"];

  var filter1 = {
      Property:"Status",
      SimpleOperator:"IN",
      Value: [-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
  };
  var res = prox.retrieve("Automation",cols,filter1);

  if (res.Results.length > 0) {
      
      var statusObj = {
  "-1":"Error",
  "0":"BuildingError",
  "1":"Building",
  "2":"Ready",
  "3":"Running",
  "4":"Paused",
  "5":"Stopped",
  "6":"Scheduled",
  "7":"Awaiting Trigger",
  "8":"InactiveTrigger"
}
      
      
      Write('<table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="5" ><tr><th colspan="4">Automation Dashboard</th></tr>')
      Write("<tr><th> Name</th><th> Automation Status</th><th>Last Run Time</th><th> ID</th></tr>")

      for (var i = 0; i < res.Results.length; i++) {
          var autoName = res.Results[i].Name;
          var autoStatusNum = res.Results[i].Status;
          var autoStatus = statusObj[autoStatusNum];
          var LastRunTime = res.Results[i].LastRunTime;
           var ID = res.Results[i].ObjectID;
        
          
          Write('<tr><td>' + autoName + '</td><td>' + autoStatus + '</td><td>' + LastRunTime + '</td><td>' + ID + '</td></tr>')
      }
      Write('</table>')
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Page search and dropdowns are frontend development / clientside. SSJS is serverside, meaning this will not be a solution based on SSJS, which also means it's not really a suitable question for here. You need to work with (client side) javascript / jquery or similar (and of course html / css). There are useful jquery libraries (dataTables & select2) that can REALLY make this fly. https://datatables.net/, https://select2.org/